# Racket FFI for struct that wraps around char array

Tags: racket, ffi

I'm trying to make racket bindings for `libgphoto2`. Its API uses [`CameraText`](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/api/structCameraText.html) struct for outputting strings, which just wraps char array.

My first attempt was:

```
(define _Camera-ptr (_cpointer 'Camera))
(define _CameraText-ptr (_cpointer 'CameraText))

(define-gphoto gp_camera_get_about
  (_fun _Camera-ptr (v : _CameraText-ptr) _GPContext-ptr
     -> _int))
```

But this was giving me segfaults (not to mention the pointer here is opaque and there are no getter functions in API).

Later on I've stumbled across https://github.com/dyoo/ffi-tutorial/blob/master/ffi/tutorial/examples/struct-with-array/struct-with-array.rkt so I've tried this:

```
(define _Camera-ptr (_cpointer 'Camera))

(define camera-text-size (* 32 1024))
(define-cstruct _CameraText ([text (_bytes/len camera-text-size)]))

(define-gphoto gp_camera_get_about
  (_fun _Camera-ptr (v : _CameraText-pointer) _GPContext-ptr
     -> _int))
```

(Where `bytes/len` is helper taken from that example)

How can I initialize this struct to mimic C `CameraText txt;`? Is there some better way to handle char arrays (and converting them to strings) than `_byte` array? Or should I go with something like:

```
(define-cstruct _CameraText ([text _string]))
```

Comment: Ask this question on the racket mailing list; You'll probably get a quicker and possibly more authoritative answer.

Comment: Did this, it's currently awaiting moderation as I send it as non-member...